# Spring data mongodb and collections schema design

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Friends, I have a question how to organize and annotate my Entities and spring data configuration for different relations?
I have User, Wallet and Balance entities with relations:

- One to One: user <-> wallet
- One to many: wallet <-> Balances

And I would like to have next schema inside mongodb:

```
> db.users.findOne()
{
    _id : ObjectID('UUUU'),
    name : 'Jason Statham'
}

> db.wallets.findOne()
{
    _id : ObjectID('WWWW'),
    user : ObjectID('UUUU')
    balances : [
     { currency: 'USD', balance: 100},
     { currency: 'EUR', balance: 530.50 }
    ]
}
```

- Wallet should contain reference to User by ObjectID and User is stored on separate collection
- Wallet should contain balances as embedded entities

Entities:

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String)
data class Wallet(val id: String, val user: User, val balances: List<Balance>)
data class Balance(val currency: String, val balance: BigDecimal)
```

My Stack is:

- Kotlin
- Spring Boot
- spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive

My expectations are:

- I'll be able to fetch `Wallet` by `UserId` declaring function: `fun getWalletByUserId(userId : String): Mono<Wallet>` at `ReactiveMongoRepository`
- `Id` will be assigned automatically when saving entities
- `Wallet` will contain `ObjectID` reference to `User`
- `Wallet` will contain `Balance` embedded collection

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution. Here is my data classes:

```
@Document
data class User(
        @Indexed
        val name: String,
        @Id
        val id: String? = null
)
@Document
data class Wallet(
        @DBRef
        val user: User,
        val balances: List<Balance>,
        @Id
        val id: String? = null
)
data class Balance(val currency: String, val balance: BigDecimal)
```

`@DBRef` annotation saves the reference to `ObjectId` in users collection. Here is an example of `Wallet` entity inside Mongo database:

```
> db.wallet.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a48cd1898318630f692508a"),
    "user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5a48cd1898318630f6925089")),
    "balances" : [
        {
            "currency" : "USD",
            "balance" : "100"
        },
        {
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "balance" : "200"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.example.model.Wallet"
}
```